# Обновление окна WPF C#

Tags: c#, wpf, windows, gui

Только начал изучать wpf, так что не кидайте тапками:)
У меня есть функция, которая создает новое окно с прогрессбаром, получает файлы по sftp (SSH.NET) и выводит прогресс получения этих файлов. Если сделать так:

```
foreach (var file in files)
            {
                if (!file.IsDirectory && !file.IsSymbolicLink)
                {
                    using (Stream fileStream = File.OpenWrite(System.IO.Path.Combine("photo_viewer_temp\\" + nowGetId.ToString(), file.Name)))
                    {
                        sftp.DownloadFile(file.FullName, fileStream);
                    }
                }
                nowDownloaded++;
                downloadProgressBar.Value = nowDownloaded;
                progressTextBlock.Text = nowDownloaded.ToString() + " из " + filesCounter.ToString();
            }
```

то окно просто "зависает". Программа загружает и сохраняет файлы, но окно не обновляется, windows показывает круглый курсор ("думает"). Но если сделать так:

```
foreach (var file in files)
            {
                if (!file.IsDirectory && !file.IsSymbolicLink)
                {
                    using (Stream fileStream = File.OpenWrite(System.IO.Path.Combine("photo_viewer_temp\\" + nowGetId.ToString(), file.Name)))
                    {
                        sftp.DownloadFile(file.FullName, fileStream);
                    }
                }
                nowDownloaded++;
                downloadProgressBar.Value = nowDownloaded;
                progressTextBlock.Text = nowDownloaded.ToString() + " из " + filesCounter.ToString();
                MessageBox.Show("Debug");
            }
```

То всё начинает работать. Как сделать так, чтобы оно обновлялось без MessageBox'а?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вообще я бы порекомендовал для этого дела исследовать технологию `MVVM`, но есть простой способ сделать и без него, просто откладывать обновление данных на диспетчеру из задачи например:

```
Task.Run(() =>
{
    foreach (var file in files)
    {
        Dispatcher.CurrentDispacher.Invoke(() =>
        {
            if (!file.IsDirectory && !file.IsSymbolicLink)
            {
                using (Stream fileStream = File.OpenWrite(System.IO.Path.Combine("photo_viewer_temp\\" + nowGetId.ToString(), file.Name)))
                {
                    sftp.DownloadFile(file.FullName, fileStream);
                }
            }

            nowDownloaded++;
            downloadProgressBar.Value = nowDownloaded;
            progressTextBlock.Text = nowDownloaded.ToString() + " из " + filesCounter.ToString();
        });
    }
});
```

Comment: Зачем в данном случае в Dispatcher передаётся скачивание файла? То есть, в потоке пула потоков только foreach, а вся тяжёла работа переходит  на каждой итерации в UI поток. Этот код никак не решает проблему.